# Google places maps Api web service post new place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-api-php-client

I just posted 2 places with the [Add Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place).

I used this model and got a success status confirmation by the webservice and then for each I got an id, and place_id, reference, scope and status

But the problem is I cannot see my new places on the google maps interface. where can I find my places to check if everything is right?

Comment: You might be able to find the created places on [Map Maker](https://www.google.com/mapmaker) and see their status.

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place#add-place-overview):

> When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added place does not appear in Text Search or Radar Search results, or to other applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.

Which means everyone can add their own places for the own use. But in order to have your place visible to other apps or the Google Maps, it needs to pass the moderation process. If your places did not show up after a week or so, then probably it didn't make it through.